# Property 'authState' does not exist on type 'AngularFireAuth' in ionic 2 app

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ionic2, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I am trying to do facebook authentication using firebase's AngularFire2.
I am following the exact same steps as this Tutorial [github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/Auth-with-Ionic2.md](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/Auth-with-Ionic2.md)

But for some reason, this doesn't work. It gives me, many errors from my provider's page. Here is my code.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';


@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
     private authState: Observable<firebase.User>;
     private currentUser: firebase.User;

     constructor(public http: Http, public afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
     console.log('Hello AuthService Provider');
     this.authState = afAuth.authState; //First error here.
     afAuth.subscribe((user: firebase.User) => { //second here
     this.currentUser = user;
      });
}

  get authenticated(): boolean {
    return this.currentUser !== null;
  }

  signInWithFacebook(): firebase.Promise<any> {
     return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider()); //third error here
      }

  signOut(): void {
    this.afAuth.signOut();
  }

  displayName(): string {
    if (this.currentUser !== null) {
      return this.currentUser.facebook.displayName;
       } else {
       return '';
       }
   }
}
```

**Errors**

`Property 'authState' does not exist on type 'AngularFireAuth'.`

```
Argument of type '(user: User) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: FirebaseAuthState) => void'. 
Types of parameters 'user' and 'value' are incompatible. 
Type 'FirebaseAuthState' is not assignable to type 'User'. 
Property 'delete' is missing in type 'FirebaseAuthState'.
```

`Property 'auth' does not exist on type 'AngularFireAuth'.`

I am pretty new to angular and ionic, please guide me here, or navigate me to a good tutorial

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solve this problem re-installing Firebase and AngularFire2:

```
npm uninstall angularfire2 --save
npm uninstall firebase --save
npm install angularfire2 firebase --save
```

Update:

```
npm install firebase @angular/fire --save
```

Answer (score 3):

The corrected answer last line is now deprecated

> npm install firebase @angular/fire --save